# 'Firma.Angajare' does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to make a project in visual studio 2013 and i have a problem with my code.

This is my code:

```
namespace Firma
{



 public partial class Angajare : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private bool isEdit = false;
    private int id = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirmeContext db = new FirmeContext();
        Angajare editedAngajare = new Angajare();
        if (Request.QueryString.Count == 1 && Request["id"] != null)
        {
            isEdit = true;
            id = Convert.ToInt32(Request["id"]);
            editedAngajare = db.Angajari.SingleOrDefault<Angajare>(a => a.IDAngajare == id);
            if (editedAngajare != null && !IsPostBack)
                txtExperienta.Text = editedAngajare.Experienta.ToString();
        }
        else
            isEdit = false;
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    PostList.DataSource = db.Posturi.ToList();
                    PostList.DataTextField = "Denumire";
                    PostList.DataValueField = "ID";
                    PostList.DataBind();
                    AngajatList.DataSource = db.Angajati.ToList();
                    AngajatList.DataTextField = "Nume";
                    AngajatList.DataValueField = "ID";
                    AngajatList.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }

         protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirmeContext db = new FirmeContext();
        Angajare editedAngajare;
        try
        {
            if (isEdit)
            {
                editedAngajare = db.Angajari.SingleOrDefault<Angajare>(d => d.IDAngajare == id);
                if (editedAngajare != null)
                {
                    editedAngajare.Experienta = int.Parse(txtExperienta.Text);
                    editedAngajare.Angajat = db.Angajati.SingleOrDefault<Angajat>(n => n.ID == int.Parse(AngajatList.SelectedValue));
                    editedAngajare.Post = db.Posturi.SingleOrDefault<Post>(p => p.IDPost == int.Parse(PostList.SelectedValue));
                    db.Entry(editedAngajare).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    litMsg.Text = "Record updated!";
                }
            }
            else
            {

                Angajare newan = new Angajare();

                newan.Experienta = int.Parse(txtExperienta.Text);
                int idAngajat=int.Parse(AngajatList.SelectedValue);
                newan.Angajat = db.Angajati.SingleOrDefault<Angajat>(n => n.ID == idAngajat);
                int idPost = int.Parse(PostList.SelectedValue);
                newan.Post = db.Posturi.SingleOrDefault<Post>(p => p.IDPost == idPost);
                db.Angajari.Add(newan);
                db.Entry(newan).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

                db.SaveChanges();
                litMsg.Text = "New Record Added!";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            litMsg.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");
    }
}

        }
```

i have a lot of errors. for example, in this line

```
editedAngajare = db.Angajari.SingleOrDefault<Angajare>(d => d.IDAngajare == id);
```

It says :

```
"Error  10  'Firma.Angajare' does not contain a definition for 'IDAngajare' and no extension method 'IDAngajare' accepting a first argument of type 'Firma.Angajare' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

The same thing for Experienta, Angajat, Post

```
 editedAngajare.Experienta = int.Parse(txtExperienta.Text);
                    editedAngajare.Angajat = db.Angajati.SingleOrDefault<Angajat>(n => n.ID == int.Parse(AngajatList.SelectedValue));
                    editedAngajare.Post = db.Posturi.SingleOrDefault<Post>(p => p.IDPost == int.Parse(PostList.SelectedValue));
                    db.Entry(editedAngajare).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

I will also show you my database:

```
 public class Angajare
{
    [Key]
    public int IDAngajare { get; set; }
    public int Experienta { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public virtual Angajat Angajat { get; set; }
}

public class Angajat
{
     [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nume { get; set; }
    public string Prenume { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAngajare { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Angajare> Angajari { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{

    [Key]
    public int IDPost { get; set; }
    public string Denumire { get; set; }
    public int ExperientaNecesara { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Angajare> Angajari { get; set; }
}
```

Please help me because i have no idea what is going wrong.
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have two classes `Angajare`. One a Web.UI.Page and one in your database model. Try to specify namespace in your linq query.